# My teacher says an odd permutation of odd order isn't possible...Why.

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't seem to understand this explanation given
There is no odd permutation of odd order. For suppose $\sigma$ is an odd permutation.
Then it can be written as
$\sigma = \tau_1 \cdots \tau_k$
where the $\tau$’s are transpositions and $k$ is odd. Now if $m$ is the order of $\sigma$, then
$\text{id} = \sigma^m = (\tau_1 \cdots \tau_k)^m$.
Thus we have written the identity as $km$ transpositions. Since the identity is even, we have
that $km$ is even. Since $k$ is odd, $m$ is even.

Comment: Which part of the argument is giving you trouble?

Comment: I feel like (12)(34)(25) would be odd and odd

Comment: Rewrite it as a product of disjoint cycles: $(12)(34)(25) = (125)(34)$. From this it is clear that the order of this permutation is $6$.

Comment: Sorry but how is it clear that it is 6? How do I find the order? I thought it was the number of terms, so 5. Since there are 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Since the cycles in the decomposition $\sigma = (125)(34)$ are disjoint, we have the property that $\sigma^n = (125)^n (34)^n$ for any power $n$ (because disjoint cycles commute). Now $(125)$ has order $3$ and $(34)$ has order $2$. So in order to have $(125)^n (34)^n = \text{id}$, it must be true that $n$ is divisible by $2$ and $3$. Since $6$ is the smallest positive integer with this property, the order of $\sigma$ is $6$.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @Bungo: Why don't you post your comment as an answer. That will enable the question to be marked answered.

Comment: @Shahab: I posted it as a comment because it didn't really seem to answer the original question (it wasn't clear what the question really was), but fair enough, better to mark it as answered since the OP is apparently satisfied now.

Comment: @Bungo: You can simply copy paste your comment in the answer box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upgrading my comment to an answer:

The OP gave the example of $\sigma = (12)(34)(25)$ and asked: isn't that an odd permutation with odd order, and therefore isn't this a counterexample to the result proved by the teacher?

The answer is no, it's not a counterexample, because the order of $\sigma$ is in fact even: it is $6$.

In order to determine the order of a permutation, it's useful to express it as a product of **disjoint** cycles. In the form $(12)(34)(25)$, the cycles $(12)$ and $(25)$ are not disjoint, which makes this form harder to work with, mainly because non-disjoint cycles do not generally commute.

We can convert it to disjoint cycle form in the usual way, by observing what the composition does to each element. It maps $1$ to $2$, and $2$ to $5$, and $5$ back to $1$, so one component cycle is $(125)$. Also, it maps $3$ to $4$ and $4$ to $3$, so the remaining component cycle is $(34)$.

Thus we see that we can express $\sigma = (125)(34)$ or $(34)(125)$. The order makes no difference since disjoint cycles commute. It's also easy to compute powers of $\sigma$. For example, $\sigma^2 = (125)(34)(125)(34) = (125)(125)(34)(34) = (125)^2 (34)^2$, and more generally, $\sigma^n = (125)^n (34)^n$.

From $\sigma^n = (125)^n (34)^n$ it is easy to find the order of $\sigma$. By definition, the order is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $\sigma^n = \text{id}$. As $(125)$ has order $3$, and $(34)$ has order $2$, we see that $\sigma^n = \text{id}$ if and only if $n$ is divisible by both $2$ and $3$. The smallest positive integer with this property is $6$, so the order of $\sigma$ is $6$.

So, this was not a counterexample to the claim in the OP, after all.